# how to test transformer ee19

Tags: transformer, debugging, testing

for practical learning i have a damaged samsung refrigerator board
i guess the problem refer to transformer
the model of transformer is EE19-220-12-A
it's have 5 pin in one side and 4 in another side
how i should test that transformer ?
should i cut it from board then start testing ?
some one pls help me ...

[image: how to test transformer ee19]

[image]
and this is the board

Comment: Not likely to be the transformer so I'd look elsewhere, possibly a flyback controller chip that drives the transformer.

Comment: how i should test that ?

Comment: Not easy to test. Usually, the procedure is fit a new chip (U9).

Comment: You need to read the site rules. This isn't isn't a forum nor an all-question-answering service. You need to ask a specific relevant question (framed into the question format) and you can expect a decent answer. Ongoing discussions about this or that need to draw to a close.

Comment: @Andyaka ok ! 
please help me to test the transformer 
i don't know how to connect the trnasformer to 220 V ac

Comment: You will be in danger of killing or blinding/burning yourself if you do that. Find a local person who can help or take a training course.

Comment: If you connect that transformer across 220VAC you'll destroy it instantly.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's not likely the transformer.
2. Look up the datasheet for the SMPS controller/switch chip and compare how the transformer should be connected. You can check it for continuity well enough in-circuit (if it's shorted or whatever it's not easy to detect).
3. It's likely the chip. Possibly made by Power Integrations. Order another one and try swapping it out, replacing any blown fuses with the same type and rating at the same time.

[image]